# Scrapy parse iframe url

Tags: python-2.7, iframe, scrapy, centos6.5

I am parsing the links off from a website, then trying to parse those links for the iframe src.

- It looks like according to the DEBUG that the first links are being parsed correctly, but I am not getting any data in my output file.
- Is it also possible to remove everything after the ? in the URL. This
  looks like embeded iframe information.

**I am running Centos 6.5 Python 2.7.5**

scrapy runspider new.py -o videos.csv

```
import scrapy

class PdgaSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "pdgavideos"
    start_urls = ["http://www.pdga.com/videos/"]

    def parse(self, response):
        for link in response.xpath('//td[2]/a/@href').extract():

            from scrapy.http.request import Request
            yield Request('http://www.pdga.com'+link, callback=self.parse_page, meta={'link':link})

    def parse_page(self, response):
        for frame in response.xpath("//player").extract():

            yield {
                'link': response.urljoin(frame)
            }
```

**Debug results**

```
DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.pdga.com/videos/2017-gbo-final-round-front-9-sexton-mcbeth-mccray-newhouse> (referer: http://www.pdga.com/videos/)
DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.pdga.com/videos/2017-glass-blown-open-fpo-rd-2-pt-1-pierce-fajkus-leatherman-c-allen-sexton-leatherman> (referer: http://www.pdga.com/videos/)
DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.pdga.com/videos/2017-gbo-final-round-back-9-sexton-mcbeth-mccray-newhouse> (referer: http://www.pdga.com/videos/)
```

**Expected results**

http://www.youtube.com/embed/tYBF-BaqVJ8

Answer (score 1):

Scrapy doese not scrape the content of the iFrames, but you can get them. First get the iframe url, then call parse on it.

```
urls = response.css('iframe::attr(src)').extract()
for url in urls :
        yield scrapy.Request(url....)
```